# django query with Q and multiple categories

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-q

I ve got the following model structure:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shop = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pizza = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza)
```

I want to find all pizzas which are with ham or cheese or both, is this the standard django way?:
    from django.db.models import Q

```
Pizza.objects.filter(Q(topping__name='ham') | Q(topping__name='cheese'))
```

How do i do it programatically, if i got a list of toppings, e.g?:

```
['ham','cheese']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with dicts and **kwargs, but there's no need: easier to just use `__in`:

```
topping_list = ['ham', 'cheese']
Pizza.objects.filter(topping__name__in=topping_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely swap the manytomany relationship to point from Pizza to Topping. 
Why would you query all toppings objects first to get the list then compare it against the Pizza? I believe you mostly want to show a pizza with their toppings and not showing a list of pizzas that have a particular topping. Would make it easier I guess (unless your app is mostly about the topping)...

Comment: Do you mean by means of performance? As far as i know, manytomany is symmetrical. In my case, toppings are an example for categories. imagine i not only have Pizza with toppings but also casserole. Then my topping class would also contain a manytomany relationship to the casserole class. then i ve got all the manytomany fields in one class

Comment: ManyToMany can be symmetrical if you use it as a relation to itself. Regarding the casserole, it does make sense then. (was not aware of this when posted the answer.) And yes I was focusing on the performace